# jQuery/JavaScript efficiency comparison when using a conditional vs. omitting it

Tags: javascript, jquery

### Description of Problem:

Let's say I want to hide an element using `jQuery.hide()`. In this example, I want to hide `#some_div` no matter what when the constructor is clicked.  So then, should I check whether it's visible to begin with, or should I simply omit the conditional altogether?

### Example:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
  if ($('#some_div').is(':visible')) {
    $('#some_div').hide();
  }
}
```

...versus...

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $('#some_div').hide();
}
```

It seems like a toss-up. If the DIV is only showing half the time, then half the time it won't need to hide it. Then again, the other half of the time it will need to perform the comparison in the conditional *and* hide it.

So which is better practice?  And which is more efficient/faster to execute?

Comment: Of course a check will be slower an less efficient than simply hiding, and unnecessary in this case considering you want to hide it "no matter what". Just skip the check.

Comment: Notice that the [`:visible` selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) does more than checking the state of the `display` css…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like just hiding is faster than testing first: http://jsperf.com/testing-visibility-vs-just-hiding

That being said, it is very unlikely that this will be a bottleneck for your application. So, I suggest that you write the code that feels more natural to you, and start doing these micro-optimizations **if** you find out that it too slow. Most of the time, it won't matter.

Comment: Awesome link! Thanks for exposing me to that site.